# Trouble Nesting a function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I have a function that I want to nest the output of into the same function
for example I have

```
p = 47; g = 2; gb = 47;
func[z_, a_, b_] := Which[
  Mod[z, 3] == 0, {g*z, a + 1, b},
  Mod[z, 3] == 1, {gb*z, a, b + 1},
  Mod[z, 3] == 2, {z*z, 2*a, 2*b}];
tort = func[1, 0, 0];
hare = func[func[1, 0, 0]];
```

Now tort value is `tort == {47,0,1}` 
and I wanna reiterate that into my `hare` variable but i can't figure out how to do it properly

basically feed `tort`'s value into hare and get
`{13,0,2}`

I'm basically trying to implement Pollard Rho for Discrete Log

Answer (score 2):

Use `Apply` (`@@`) to replace the head of the `List` with `func`.

```
hare = func @@ tort;
```

Or equivalently:

```
hare = Apply[func, tort];
```

Note however that while `func[47,0,1] == func @@ tort`, it does not equal `{13,0,2}`. If that's the expected answer, double check your definitions.

For repeated nesting, such as with `Nest`, it may be useful to write an anonymous function that wraps that, such as `func @@ # &`:

```
Nest[func @@ # &, {1, 0, 0}, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way could be to define the function like `func[{z_, a_, b_}] := ...`